# Counting the sum coins, using Matlab Image Processing Toolbox

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to develop a program which would find a circular objects (coins) and measure their size, based on which I will assign values. I need to take into account the position form which a particular photo is taken, e.g. angle. Since some coins will appear larger than others from different angles, the value assignment will be defective, hence I am trying to solve it with projective transformation (projecting a tilted image) and so far, I am failing to project oblique photos in a way that produces more or less equal measurements of the diameters. My code is below:

```
    I = imread('coins2.jpg');
    imshow(I);
    M = ginput(4);
    X = ginput(4);
    P = maketform('projective', M, X);
    I = imtransform(I, P, 'nearest');
    G = rgb2gray(I);
    K = medfilt2(G);
    [centers,radii] = imfindcircles(K,[90 140],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.95);
    h = viscircles(centers, radii);
    arr = [];   
       for r = 1:length(radii)
          if (radii(r)) >= 105
             arr(r) = 1;
          elseif (radii(r)) < max(radii) && radii(r) > 100
             arr(r) = 0.2;
          elseif(radii(r)) < 100 && (radii(r)) > 95
             arr(r) = 0.05;
          elseif (radii(r)) < 95 && (radii(r)) > 90
             arr(r) = 0.1;
          end       
       end
   result = sum(arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the option to detect corners in the pictures (for example, coins on a rectangular support), you could use this Matlab file:
https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35531-perspective-control-correction to detect 4 corners manually or automatically to correct the perspective, and you would then be able to use imfindcircles as usual.